# Azure custom domain not working

Tags: azure, dns, web

I'm using Azure and have a website hosted on it.
These are my DNS records:
[image: My DNS Records]

However, when I try to add the domain to azure, I get this error:

> A CNAME record pointing from www.mydomain.com to mydomain.azurewebsites.net was not found. Alternative record awverify.www.mydomain.com to awverify.mydomain.azurewebsites.net was not found either.

If I visit the page, I get this error:
[image: The error]

Am I configuring something wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Name entries for the CNAME records are configured wrong.  They should be:

- www for 123.azurewebsites.net
- awverify for awverify.123.azurewebsites.net

You might want to check a quick video I made to explain the process:
[www.azurerocks.com/JDDzhbB-8fk](http://www.azurerocks.com/JDDzhbB-8fk)

Comment: Holy cow! Thanks for the video. I'm wondering why Microsoft does not put this on the Azure documentation --> https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-godaddy-custom-domain-name